# Efficient algorithm to remove duplicates from a list made up of objects of a custom class

Tags: algorithm, processing-efficiency, memory-efficient

I have a custom class. The class has float, date, char and string attributes. A sample class definition is as below.

class MyClass { string str1; string str2; date date1; date date2; float amount1; float amount2; char char1, char char2 };

The task is to identify duplicates within a list of objects of that class. Every object can be marked a duplicate of only one other object. For all duplicates identified for an object that is retained a list of duplicates is to be created. A certain operation is performed and eventually the duplicates are removed and only the unique objects are retained. This second operation referred here is irrelevant to this task and hence is not mentioned in detail.

I have defined a comparison operator to detect whether two objects of that class are the same or not. The comparison is based on comparing the individual attributes of that class and then looking for combinations of those attributes matching them as a set to determine whether the two objects are identical or not. The comparison of individual attributes is fuzzy. A rule base for checking combinations of attributes of the class matching is then referred to determine whether the two objects are to be considered identical or not.

The current algorithm has a time complexity of O(n^2).

What is the most efficient algorithm to remove duplicates from the list of objects of that class?

The maximum number of objects in that list is of the order of thousand or at most two thousand. Each instance of that class does not consume large amount of memory. Typically, the number of objects in the list is less than 50-100. Our analytical research suggest that we do not have more than 2 or 3 percentage of duplicates across a large set of examples of what can be in the list. False positives and false negatives are to be avoided. This again is outside the context of the problem since it is a function of the comparison operator that I am not trying to address.

I was thinking instead of the current O(n^2) algorithm an approach to sort the list and then use a single pass to find and delete duplicates will yield O(n* log n) + O(n) time complexity. This latter algorithm for large n - say > 10 will perform better than an algorithm with O(n ^2) time complexity. Sorting may require writing a less than / greater than operator which can be done.

I would appreciate options with considerations of space and time complexity.

Comment: The pretty obvious choice is to additionally define a hash function on your object type and implement a multimap, most easily a hash table where the keys are the objects and values are lists of pointers to the duplicates. This will be fast and memory efficient.  If you're working in a language with a reasonable date types and/or libraries like Java or Python, it will take about 30 lines of code.  In C it will be maybe 100 (without tests).

Comment: Do you have a few thousand objects, or a few thousand duplicates?

Comment: You start with a list of objects, possibly containing duplicates. You want the output to be a dictionary whose key is the object key, and the value is a list of objects that contain that key? Seems like the easiest way is to just go through the list and build the dictionary. When you're done, scan the dictionary and output a new list that contains the first object that's mapped to each key.

Comment: @Gene - A few thousand objects (worst case) with between 2 and 3 % duplicates. Is it going to be more efficient if we sorted the list and then did the comparison ? What would be the chosen algorithm for the fastest comparison. Is there anything better than O(n^2).

Comment: @Jim - What can give better than O(n^2) performance ? That is the time complexity of the current implementation which for large n slows down tremendously. Most of the time there is less than 100 objects in the list.

Comment: The technique I outline is O(n). But you have to clarify your requirements before I can give a complete answer. Please give brief description of the objects, perhaps a stripped-down class declaration. Are the duplicates *identical*, or do they just have identical key values? What *exactly* do you want as output from this function? Provide a small example of an input list, the desired output list, and the desired dictionary. Remember, you need to give us enough information to help you. We don't know anything about your problem except what you tell us.

Comment: The comparison operator I mentioned in a fuzzy operator. The class has numeric, date and string attributes and they seldom do match in all attributes. The comparison thus has a fuzzy comparison of individual attributes and further a combination of these attributes matching results in a match. So, determining a hash value to compare the two objects will not work.

Comment: Side note (if using sorting)- To sort a list of objects of the class it is possible to write a <, >, = operator. I was thinking instead of the current O(n^2) algorithm an approach to sort the list and then use a single pass to find and delete duplicates will yield O(n* logn) + O(n) time complexity. This latter algorithm for large n say > 10 will perform better than an algorithm with O(n ^2) algorithm.

Comment: class MyClass { string str1; string str2; date date1; date date2; amount amount1; amount amount2;   char char1, char char 2 }; There is a rule base that tells us which of str1, str2, date1, date2, amount1, amount2, char1, char2 when matching result in the two objects being considered a match. The comparison operator implements this rule base. This is existing logic that cannot be changed in working towards an efficient algorithm.

Comment: Most or all of that information should have been in the question from the start.

Comment: I added it, so am looking forward to thoughts. Is the sorting followed by a single pass sweep (i.e. an O(n * logn) + O(n) algorithm) a viable alternative to an O(n) algorithm ?

Comment: First, rather than putting answers to my questions in comments, edit your question and add clarification. Second, you still need to tell me what *exactly* you want as output. You said that there's a dictionary involved, but you need to clarify whether the dictionary is input, or if you want it to be part of the output. Also, sorting is definitely a good way to start. It's simple and should be reasonably fast if you're not doing this hundreds of times per second. I would recommend that you try it. If it works, and is fast enough, then you're done.

Comment: @Jim - The duplicates are not deleted permanently at the end of the de-duplication algorithm but eventually will be. They are moved to a different list as an intermediate step. The dictionary maintains a mapping between the ones that are retained at the end of the de-duplication intermediate step with the key being the object that is being retained and the value being a list of objects (or pointers to objects) that were a duplicate of that object. Any object in this duplicates list is a duplicate of a single object that is maintained as a key of this dictionary. Hope this clarifies further.

Comment: That's not particularly helpful. Unless you *edit your question* and add complete requirements, including answering the questions I've asked, I can't help you.

Comment: @Jim and others - Edits done to have all information in the original question. Thank you all for comments and suggestions that you have and may now offer.